# Explore/save iCloud Drive iOS

Tags: ios, icloud, icloud-drive

I want to develop an app that uses iCloud Drive to upload projects and also be able to retrieve these projects.

Every project would have its own folder with its own resources such as images, text documents etc...

An example structure would be like this:

```
+ Project 1
|
|+ Images:
|   - Image 1
|   - Image 2
|
|+ Documents:
|   - Document 1
```

Firstly, what I want to do, is to be able to create a new project and save the project resources to iCloud Drive.

Then, from the same device or another one, I'd like to be able to scan all project folders such as `Project 1`,`Project 2`... retrieve all data and save it to the `Documents` folder so that I can access that content every time offline and fill up the app contents.

I've been doing some research of how to achieve this but I haven't found such information.

Until now, I've managed to be able to access to the `ubiquityIdentityToken`. How should I proceed from here?